# javascript sliding div left/right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy guys! I want to make a slide toggle effect of a div. Below is the code in my html file. My div is 500px wide by 50px height. I want to make it slide left/right over the screen when pressed on the first image inside the div. This is a toolbox that contains a couple of icons inside. The first image at the left - left.jpg should be a swop image(some kind of button - this is an arrow pointing left and after moving the div this arrow should point right - I mean the picture should be changed). I looked over the web and saw different examples with jQuery but could not find the exact solution for my needs. I know this is a great community and hope that somebody will help to deal with this! Thank you in advance!!!

```
<script> 
$(function(){
$("#clicky").click(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'500px'},'slow');   
});
});
</script>
<div id="slide">
<img  id="clicky" src="left.jpg" width="15" height="15" />
Div Content here...</div>
```

Comment: did you find or tried your code?

Comment: you want to float the image to the right when you press on it?

Comment: have you tried to code this up by yourself before asking? If yes, can you please post that here also?

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for quick reply. This is a test link: http://www.k-prim.biz/test/test.html

Comment: I found this code that is close to my needs but it does not toggle the content and I need to use the toggle image/button inside the sliding content

Comment: So, you want the div to go back when you click the image again?

Answer (score 0):

As a third argument you could pass a function that will be fired when the animation is finished. Something like this:

```
$("#slide").animate({marginLeft:'500px'},'slow', function(){
  $("img#clicky").attr("src", "right.jpg");
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works for swopping the image - thanks! But what about toggle the div?